# How to get points along motion path in anime.js

Tags: javascript, svg, anime.js

I am making an animation along an SVG path with [anime.js](http://animejs.com/).

I have copied the example from [here](http://animejs.com/documentation/#motionPath) and everything is working fine.

I would like to be able to get all the x and y points along the tweened path, at once (ie on init of my script, not one one as it tweens) to use to make a static shape, but I don't know where to begin. I have looked at the [source code](https://github.com/juliangarnier/anime/blob/master/anime.js) but am unsure if there is a function available for this.

I understand there would be more or less points depending on the duration of the tween. With a standard tween, say moving from 0 - 250 I can imagine how I could just count between the from and the to but because a path does not simply increment, rather it rises and falls, I don't know I would go about getting the points.

Apologies if this question is not clear, I hope I have articulated what I'm after but if you need any more info to advise, please ask.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<path>` elements have a couple of methods that you should find useful.

- `getPointAtLength(length)`
  Gets the X,Y coordinates of a point `length` along the path
- `getTotalLength()`
  Gets the total length of the path

An example of typical usage:

```
var  mypath = document.getElementById("mypath");
var  pathLength = mypath.getTotalLength();
var  pt = mypath.getPointAtLength(pathLength / 2);  // halfway along the path
console.log("x="+pt.x+" y="+pt.y);
```

Comment: That exactly what I need, thanks so much. I wish I had known about that before. Much appreciated.